# Changing a character in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrays

Before reading this question, i would like to post a disclaimer.

I have read that we have functions which can directly replace the character in a string(string.replace),i just want to try the manual method for doing this.

Here's the code that i just wrote.

```
string = bytearray("abc'defgh",'utf-8')

for value in range(0,9):
    if string[value]=='h' or string[value]=='c':
        string[value]=='i'
    else:
        print('''Word's are not the same''')


print(string.decode("utf-8"))
```

I would also like the people who are giving me the answer to also explain a little about bytearray() as i just saw this function and i'm trying it.

Thanks!!

Comment: `string[value]=='i'` -> `string[value]= 'i'`

Comment: you didn't say what the problem was.

Comment: Consider using the `translate` method. It's much faster than doing this manually: `text = "abc'defgh"; text.translate({ord('h'): 'i', ord('c'): 'i'}) ->
"abi'defgi"`

Comment: Hint: print `string[value]` before your `if` statement.

Comment: You didn't tell us what your problem was, neither did you print your actual/desired output.

Comment: Mr Bakuriu,could you please elaborate on the workings of the translate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned there are better ways to do this, but I guess it makes sense as a learning exercise to explore how `bytearray` works.

Your `if` tests will never succeed. Those tests assume that a `bytearray` is an array of single character strings, but that's not correct. A `bytearray` is effectively an array of *integers*, so your tests need to compare the elements in `string` to integers. You can do that using actual integers, but it's more convenient to use an `in` test with a bytes object. And when you make your replacement you need to supply an integer, or you will get this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here's a new version of your code. I've changed the name of `string` to `arr` because it's not a string, so calling it `string` is confusing.

I've also changed the `for` loop to use the `enumerate` function, which iterates over an iterable object, yielding (index, element) pairs.

```
arr = bytearray("abc'defgh", 'utf-8')

replacement = ord('i')
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if v in b'ch':
        arr[i] = replacement
    print(v, chr(v))

print(arr)
print(arr.decode('utf-8'))
```

**output**

```
97 a
98 b
99 c
39 '
100 d
101 e
102 f
103 g
104 h
bytearray(b"abi\'defgi")
abi'defgi
```